# Getting the value basing on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value inside this `<p>` tag using a jquery code which starts with a `$` sign, i only had to make it work using innerHTML.

Here is my sample code:

```
<p id="nameDisplay">Sample Name</p>
```

Here is my innerHTML code that worked:

```
document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML
```

I want to learn how to code it using jquery, thanks in advance.

Comment: start with http://learn.jquery.com/ and http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=https://api.jquery.com/html/&ei=2CQDU-StAY6MrgeB54GICw&usg=AFQjCNEeEKcT7eGZMno3p0CKQO6I8ly4FQ)

`$('#nameDisplay').text()`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/GFsec/)**

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4459992/1778834) on difference between `.text()` and `.html()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the HTML contents of your paragraph as well as using `#` to target an element by `id`:

```
$('#nameDisplay').html();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to get the element and [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) in place of `innerHTML` The jQuery **selectors** are one of its salient features, you can learn more [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$('#nameDisplay').html()
```

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another
>   selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery
>   performs an additional check before identifying the element as a
>   match.

Answer (score 0):

If you required text without html then:

```
$('#nameDisplay').text()
```

if required with html tags then:

```
$('#nameDisplay').html()
```