# console.log() only if AJAX data changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i made this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.storage').html("");
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('./playcommand.php', function(data) {
            if($('.storage').html() !==  data){
              $('.result').html(data);
              console.log("neu");
            }
        });
    }, 500); // 5 seconds
</script>
```

My Intention is to `console.log("neu");` only if data from AJAX is different than the data before, thats why i created a div "storage" where i save the latest data which was not equal to the data before.

But it doesnt works, it logs always "neu", even if the data isnt different.

UPDATE:

My new Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var storage = $('.storage').text();
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('./playcommand.php', function(data) {
            if($('.storage').text != data){
              $('.result').html(data);
              console.log("neu");
            }
        });
    }, 500); // 5 seconds
</script>
```

Still doesnt work

Comment: Try changing `if($('.storage').html() !==  data){`  to `if($('.storage').text() !==  data){`

Comment: What is the value of `$('.storage').html()`?  What is the value of `data`?  *Are* they ever the same?  Note that your code never seems to *modify* the value of `$('.storage').html()`.

Comment: `500` aren't 5 seconds, it's a half seconds. Add one 0 at the end.

Comment: @klenium Yes i know, i didnt change the comment.  If the new data changes storage than data and storage are the same strings.

Comment: Come on man, take 1/2 a second to format your code before posting it.

Comment: `text` needs to be `text()`. Read my comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure text vs html is not his problem, unless `data` contains some [special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459992/differences-between-text-and-html-with-escaped-and-characters)

Comment: Why adding another element? why not using a variable or using `.result` element?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are putting blank before compare. Remove this line from first line,

```
 $('.storage').html("");
```

Or keep string in one variable to compare

```
 var storage = $('.storage').text();
 $('.storage').html("");
```

And then compare `data` with `storage`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var storage = $('.storage').text().trim();;
     $('.storage').html("");
     setInterval(function(){
        $.get('./playcommand.php', function(data) {
            if(storage != data.trim()){
              $('.result').html(data);
                console.log("neu");
            }
        });
    }, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: Share exact both string , or just try by putting one as static like `if (storage === 'mytext')` if it runs means you need to use trim function or data is incorrect

Comment: @AppleWeb: did you try this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 $('.storage').html("");
```

this line makes storage blank remove it or place it after the function